# WPF Performance Problems with derived TextBox controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, profiling

I have a WPF application that renders input forms based on form-configurations saved in a database.

The forms have many controls (100+) and most of these controls are derived from a TextBox-control. On some machines (fast Hardware, Win7 32Bit, also some elder, Windows XP 32Bit), after entering data to a lot of these forms, input performance goes down. Every keystroke gets a delay of some milliseconds and the only solution to resolve this is to close the application and restart it.

My derived control overrides the metadata of the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty` to set a custom template.

I'm currently reasearching the app in SciTech memory profiler, but maybe someone has already experienced a similar problem with derived TextBoxes and can give me a hint and spare me some more hours/days investigating the problem?

**Update**
Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271884/wpf-memory-leak-with-derived-textboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have something stopping the controls on the "used forms" being GCed.

Firstly opening and use as many forms as possible looking at the windows task manager to see if you memory usage is going up – if it is not there is no point looking for memory leeks

Check you are removing all events handlers you forms/controls have put on any long lived objects.

Check that any objects you databind to implement  INotifyPropertyChanged, see [KB938416](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us)

I have in the past had good results using the [Red Gate memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

Comment: +1 Indeed I have found a memory bug like you have described in your fourth paragraph. I'm investigating further and it's also not clear if the memory bug has a direct relation to the delay problem, we will see... The problem desription can be found here :http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us, maybe I will post a related answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to have controls created that the user can’t see, 100+ controls will have a cost.

Can you use something list a list control in virtual mode, so your TextBox controls are only created when visible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, the forms are represenations of paper forms with complex formating. I don't see any possibility to do UI virtualization or any sort of lazy control-creation. The problem however is not the amount of controls. The problem arises after opening and using about 50 of these forms.